# build a web page with coordinated images

Tags: html, image

well I'm asked to build a web page that has some objects (actually images) to be placed in a coordinated places...this is what it looks like, the words A, B, C, D are click-able images (links) and we don't want to make a full background or something...

Comment: BTW, I tried with <table> but couldn't get a good result...if table is a good choice, then please show me a sample code...thnx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your images are named `imgM`, `imgO`, `imgR` and `imgA`, you can absolutely position your images in specific places to accomplish what you want:

```
#imgM
{
   position: absolute 
   left: 57px;
   top: 92px;
}
#imgO
{
   position: absolute 
   left: 365px;
   top: 366px;
}
#imgR
{
   position: absolute 
   left: 652px;
   top: 459px;
}
#imgA
{
   position: absolute 
   left: 810px;
   top: 182px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, the code is great but the problem is I want to centerize them I mean I want to align them center on every screen resolution, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

if the position of the objects (images) should be fixed, you can use `position: absolute` css style and give corresponding `left` and `top` coordinates to images

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
float:left;
```

and

```
float:right;
```

in your css
or you can also use

```
margin:5 5 5 5;
```

(top-right-bottom-left)

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
<div>
<img src="" style="float:left;">
<img src="" style="float:right;">
</div>

<div style="clear:both;">
<img src="" style="float:left;">
<img src="" style="float:right;">
</div>
```

No need of using tables. You can get it by using divs